# Where can I find the Senate vote for Lynn Scarlett to be Deputy Secretary of the Interior?

Tags: united-states, senate, cabinet, political-appointments

The Deputy Secretary of Interior is appointed by the President with the advise and consent of the Senate.  I cannot seem to find the voting record for this woman who became Deputy Secretary of the Interior in 2005.  I do not know what day the vote happened.

I went to these links here:

- https://www.senate.gov/legislative/LIS/roll_call_lists/vote_menu_109_1.htm
- https://www.senate.gov/legislative/LIS/roll_call_lists/vote_menu_108_2.htm

But I could not find the nomination of this woman.

Which Senators abstained, voted for and against, Lynn Scarlett when she was appointed Deputy Secretary of the Interior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was no recorded vote on the nomination.

[PN227](https://www.congress.gov/nomination/109th-congress/227) — Patricia Lynn Scarlett — Department of the Interior

> 11/18/2005 - Confirmed by the Senate by Voice Vote.

Answer (score 4):

A quick search on congress.gov turned up [this result](https://www.congress.gov/nomination/109th-congress/227?q=%7B%22search%22%3A%22lynn%20scarlett%22%7D&s=1&r=7), which seems to suggest that this was a voice vote (i.e. individual votes were not recorded at all) that happened on 18 November 2005.